# Why am I getting error 3078 on my SELECT query?

Tags: ms-access

I've started to try and write some VBA to execute some queries and I've got stuck at the first hurdle. This is giving an error 3078 which apparently means it can't find the table or query. The table definitely exists and is spelt properly. Indeed the SQL runs fine - I tested it. What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Function Tester()

    str_tbl = "tblGames_atp"

    str_mkvrec = "SELECT * FROM " & str_tbl

    dbl_fs_pct = DSum("FS", str_mkvrec)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reference SQL statement in domain aggregate function, not even a variable set to that statement. Must reference table or query object name. Could reference variable with name string but variable not really needed in this code. If you want function to return a value to calling source, then need to set function value.

```
Public Function Tester()
    Tester = DSum("FS", "tblGames_atp")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks and useful to know!